# How to create a multiple JSON objects inside an Array in java selenium

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, rest

I wanted the ouput in this format using some **loop**, because the data contains more than 20 objects.

```
"childTargets": [
            {
                "name": "true",
                "rank": 86438458
            },
            {
                "name": "false",
                "rank": 86647857
            }
        ]
```

i do not want in this way to right because code will be too long

```
.put(new JSONObject().put("name", "INDIA")
```

Please help me on this

Comment: [REVIEW] Answer depends on your data source for these records. Can you tell what source/format you use ? And what have you tried sofar ? post code so that people can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would craete an aarry with all names and an array all ranks and the loop through them.

Here is an example:

```
    String[] names; // all your Names
    int[] ranks; // all your Ranks the first rank belongs to the first name.

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(); // Create an JSONArray Object.
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("name", names[i]);
        jsonObject.put("rank", ranks[i]);
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }
```

If you have more than two properties consider using one list with strucks or objects who contain all of them instead of sperad arrays.

Comment: Hello Stroby, Thanks very much, it really saved my time.Thanks a lot. it worked great.
public class dsadsd {
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] names = { "india", "usa" }; int[] ranks = { 1, 2 }; 
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   jsonObject.put("name", names[i]);
   jsonObject.put("rank", ranks[i]);
   jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
  }obj.put("childTargets", jsonArray);
  System.out.println(obj);}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library such as `Gson` to marshal POJO's to json cleanly.

Define a java class such as:

```
public class ChildTargets {

    private List<Target> children;

    // getters and setters

    public static class Target {
        private String name;
        private String rank;

        // getters and setters
    }
```

Then instantiate the ChildTargets class with any Target objects you want using a loop, then call:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(childTargets);
```

You should get a json String in the form of:

```
{  
   "childTargets":[  
      {  
         "name":"obj1",
         "rank":"rank1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"obj2",
         "rank":"rank2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Hello smith, i do not want to use POJO. I have used Stroby inputs, it worked awesome. Thanks smith to you too:-)

Comment: hi @stroby  please help me on this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63522417/hello-i-need-below-response-and-how-to-pass-targetname-and-selectedtargetoptions